# Series - Parallel Resistor Calculations

Tags: resistors, resistance, parallel, series

[image]

Hi,
I would be very grateful if anyone could shed some light on the below diagram as I'm trying to calculate the total resistance between A and B in this series parallel configuration.

10 and 20 are in parallel and 90, 70, and 80 are also in parallel but then I get confused with it as it then looks like two series circuits connected in parallel between A and B when you re-draw the diagram???

Thanks.

Comment: 90, 70, and 80 are not in parallel. 70 and 80 in parallel are in series with 60 which is all parallel with 90.

Answer (score 3):

1. Re-draw your diagram

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1L0Fi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you can prove to yourself why these two circuits are equivalent, it should become apparent what is in parallel and what is in series.

Answer (score 0):

Break the problem down so that eventually you end up with two parallel ( // ) resistance which will then give you the impedance between A &B.

LEFT of a --> b

X = 10//20 + 30 + 40

RIGHT

Y = (( 70//80 + 60 ) // 90 ) + 50

The: X // Y

This looks like homework though, so I shall leave it there ;)

Comment: Hi ,

Thanks to everyone for the great help as it can get somewhat frustrating at times but I have a much better understanding of it now.

Cheers